# FFMPEG overlay filter partly conversion

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, blend

I am trying to apply the overlay filter on the video to blend a single image for a few seconds. Since my video duration is about 1 min it seems wasteful when FFMPEG tries to re-encode the whole video again instead of reencoding the portion of the video that needs to be altered.

My blend video command is:

```
ffmpeg -i beach.mp4 -i logo.png 
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" 
-pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Does anyone knows how can I avoid this ?
(I was thinking to split the video, but is seems that the video can not be split accurately by specifying the start and the end frame)

Comment: You can encode the 20 second segment with the overlay as a separate file, then trim the first ~20 seconds from the original with `-c copy`. Then use the [concat demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) to join them. Note that the two resulting segments to be joined must match parameters (codec, timebase, etc), and you'll need to cut on a keyframe for best results. A lot of work for a one minute video. My laziness would tell me just re-encode it all or simply not deal with the overlay. If you're using a web based player you can have it add the logo instead.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thanks, but this operation will be executed many times, not just once. That is why I need performance.

Comment: I assumed that was a possibility, but you didn't mention it in the question. You should show the complete console output from your command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Sorry for not mentioning. That was the complete output; I did not write anything else as I stuck on the first step.

Comment: Does the overlay have to happen for exactly 20 seconds?

Comment: If a video splitting by keyframes is faster I can tolerate this, so in short I can tolerate inaccuracy. If this is the case, I have to know which time stamp(s) exactly is used for cropping.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're okay with some inaccuracy, I suggest the following method:

**Segment the video input**

```
ffmpeg -i beach.mp4 -c copy -segment_time 20 -f segment beach_seg%02d.mp4
```

**Overlay logo on first segment**

```
ffmpeg -i beach_seg00.mp4 -loop 1 -i logo.png 
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:shortest=1" 
-pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy overlay.mp4
```

**Concat segments**

First, prepare a text file `segments.txt`

```
file 'overlay.mp4'
file 'beach_seg01.mp4'
file 'beach_seg02.mp4'
file 'beach_seg03.mp4'
...
```

Then, concat

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i segments.txt -c copy beach_with_logo.mp4
```

The caveat here is that the timebase of overlay.mp4 may not match those of the beach segments. In which case, check the timebase of one of the beach segments (the `tbn`) and add `-video_track_timescale <tbn>` to the overlay command.

Comment: Thanks  a lot (Mulvya and LordNeckbeard)! Can you just explain me if I cut a video to three pieces and I need to process the middle piece with a software, and that software requires the frame offset, how should i obtain that frame offset ? (I used force_keyframes to set the keyframes and then I did the cutting - is this OK ?)